# How do Squish knows that it can execute another line?

Tags: squish

There is a timeout of, by default 20 seconds, on Squish 6.2.0 (example given).
How Squish knows after this timeout that it can execute another line ?

Comment: Do you want Squish to ignore that it could not find the object and proceed executing the test script? For that you can use exception handling, see [How to Handle Exceptions Raised in Test Scripts](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/ug-how-to-handle-exceptions-raised-in-test-scripts.html#ug-how-to-handle-exceptions-raised-in-test-scripts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squish GUI settings have a default timeout wait(seconds). If the object is not found, user is given with a error message "Object not Found", Choose from either(debug,throw error).

Scenario 2 : Timeout can be injected for example ( once user logs in , and if the landing page/window takes few minutes to load, you have assign a hard coded timeout(which can be more than 20 seconds)

For more information, Click on Edit-> Server-> Settings to check the default timeout on Squish tool.

*More Information found at : https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/ide.views.html#ide.the-settings.view*

*There is a timeout of, by default 20 seconds, on Squish 6.2.0 (example given). How Squish knows after this timeout that it can execute another line ?*

Usually this is achieved by test cases where it compares for input you are trying to validate. Input can be either : Text,Image,Value. Or you can write a test case that it just clicks on a object and moves to the (next line/Next Test case) after the default timeout.

Hope this answers your question.